# ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord Exception raised when parent is readonly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following two models:

```
# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail

  serialize :mail_opt_out, Set

  before_create :generate_token

  has_many :wallets
  has_many :tickets, through: :wallets

  ...

  # We have a special seeded customer with id -1 that we don't want changing
  def readonly?
    persisted? && id < 0
  end
end


# app/models/ticket.rb
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SparkCast

  has_paper_trail

  belongs_to :price
  belongs_to :basket
  belongs_to :occurrence

  has_one :event,       through: :occurrence
  has_one :wallet,      through: :basket
  has_one :basket_type, through: :basket      
  has_one :customer,    through: :basket

  delegate :id, to: :customer, allow_nil: true

  ...

  def admit
    ensure_can_admit

    self.state = 'admitted'
    self.save!
  end
  cast_on :admit, room: :admittance

  def as_cast
    {
      id: id,
      customer_id: customer_id
    }
  end
end
```

The relevant association is a little convoluted, but is customers -> wallets -> baskets -> tickets.

When I call `admit` on an instance of a ticket that belongs to our customer with id -1, (which is read only) I get an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` exception.

I'm confused as to what is causing this, as neither ticket nor customer have any `before_update` callbacks. If I change

```
 has_one :customer, through: :basket
```

to

```
 delegate :customer, to: :basket
```

then everything is fine. Something seems to be either trying to update the customer, or at least checking if it is readonly.

I've done a bit of stepping through the save procedure using `byebug`, but haven't been able to find anything useful.

What is likely to be checking if an associated model is readonly, and how do I get around this? Is using delegate the best option here?

#### Edited to add:

Also including SparkCast, which I had omitted previously. Removing the `cast_on` method from my ticket model is fixing the problem.

```
# app/models/concerns/spark_cast.rb
module SparkCast
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def cast_on(*args)
      # Options are the last argument.
      options = args.pop

      room   = options[:room]

      args.each do |operation|
        class_eval do
          begin
            alias_method "#{operation}_without_cast", operation

            define_method operation do |*args|
              cast_hash = as_cast

              ...

              send("#{operation}_without_cast", *args)
              cast(room, operation, cast_hash)
            end
          rescue NameError => e
            raise "#{e.name} has not been defined yet. Include cast_on after method definition"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Backtrace:

```
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:481:in `create_or_update'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `transaction'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:393:in `save_has_one_association'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:188:in `block in add_autosave_association_callbacks'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `update_record'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `update_record'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 - activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
 -  () home/hayden/development/SparkSeat/api/app/models/ticket.rb:79:in `admit'
```

Comment: Might be useful to post the backtrace on the read only error. Also, I wonder if you've tried without `has_paper_trail` in the mix just to rule that out?

Comment: @Shadwell - I have added the backtrace as requested. I have tried without paper_trail with no success.

Comment: However, what I have found is that removing the `cast_on` line (previously omitted for breivity) did fix the problem. Although I still can't see why that would be causing AR to check my customer...

Comment: Can't see anything obvious but the delegate of `:id` to customer is making me uneasy - have you tried without that too? It seems something is setting the `has_one :customer` to be autosaved - it's an option on the association but obviously not one you've set yourself.

Comment: @Shadwell If I remove `delegate :id`, and change `customer_id` in `as_cast` to `customer.id`, the readonly exception still occurs. If I return the `delegate :id` and simply comment out the `customer_id` line, the exception does not occur (but I then don't have that data in the hash...)